# Gaussian process with independent stationary increments and discontinuous mean and variance

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Consider a problem and its proof at the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673820/gaussian-process-with-independent-increments). The problem boils down to what follows: prove that a pathwise-continuous Gaussian process with independent stationary increments has continuous mean and variance functions. Obviously, the pathwise-continuity condition can be replaced by the condition of continuity in probability. But is it true that the continuity condition can be completely dropped? Or there exists a Gaussian process with independent stationary increments that has discontinuous mean and variance?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A process with independent stationary increments that is continuous in probability is called a [Levy process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process). Perhaps it will help to look for discussions on dropping the continuity condition for Levy processes.

Comment: I found an old paper that seems relevant : M.B. Marcus, Gaussian processes with stationary increments possessing discontinuous sample paths. *Pacific Journal of Mathematics*, **Vol. 26, No. 1,** 1968.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_t$ be a Gaussian process with independent stationary increments (Gaussian Levy process). Set \begin{align*}
a(t) &:= \mathbb{E}[X_t]\\
b(t) &:= \mathrm{Var}[X_t]
\end{align*}
Note that $a,b$ are additive functions and $b$ is nondecreasing. Because the graph of an additive nonlinear function is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $b$ must be linear, thus continuous. But $a$ can be discontinuous. In fact, the degenerate process $X'_t := \mu(t)$, where $\mu$ is any additive nonlinear function, is exactly an example of a Gaussian Levy process that has discontinuous mean.