# Limit of a function on subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

Answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400086/gaussian-process-with-independent-stationary-increments-and-discontinuous-mean-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) led me to a situation which I think should have been covered in first-year calculus, but honestly now I can't remember that. Suppose we know that for some function $f$ and each $r\in\Bbb R$ we have $f(\frac rn) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Does it imply that there exists $\lim\limits_{r\to0}f(r) = 0$?

My guess is: no. For example, I can fix a monotonically decreasing sequence $a_k$ of irrational numbers that converges to $0$, set $f(\frac {a_k}n) = \frac kn$ and $f(r) = 0$ otherwise. It seems that $f$ satisfies my convergence conditions, but obviously it does not converge to $0$. Would you help me verifying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $f(x)=17$ for $x=\pi^{-k}$, $k=1,2,3,\dots$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. For any real $r$ there's at most one positive integer $n$ such that $f(r/n)=17$ (because if $r/m=\pi^{-j}$ and $r/n=\pi^{-k}$ then dividing we get $n/m=\pi^{k-j}$ and the left side is rational and the right side isn't) so $f(r/n)\to0$ but $\lim_{r\to0}f(r)$ doesn't exist since there's a sequence tending to zero with $f(r)=17$.

[Thanks to user Medo for pointing out a typo which I have corrected.]

Comment: Thanks, that's an even simpler example.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Is every positive power of $\pi$ irrational ? We have $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational but its square is rational.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson In the second line you mean to say "given $r>0$, there is at most one integer  $n$ such that $f(r/n)=17$".

Comment: @Medo, $\pi$ is *transcendental*. No polynomial in $\pi$ with integer coefficients vanishes, save the zero polynomial.